# Override de Propriedade

Tags: python, python-3.x, propriedade

Segundo alguns exemplos que encontrei estou tentando implementar um override de uma `property`, porém o override não funciona. Acho que esse é um tema ainda meio obscuro com poucos exemplos e pouca informação a respeito. Segue meu exemplo:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Person(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.age = age

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value


class Myself(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, age, tel):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.tel = tel

    @Person.name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        super().name = 'override'


class Wife(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, age, tel):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.tel = tel



ms = Myself('Matheus Saraiva', 36, '988070350')
wi = Wife('Joice Saraiva', 34, '999923554')

print(ms.name)
```

Se minha implementação está correta, o resultado do `print` deveria ser:

```
>>> override
```

mas o resultado está sendo:

```
>>> Matheus Saraiva
```

Ou seja, aparentemente o override não está funcionando. O que está errado na minha implementação?

Comment: Acabei que perceber que o resultado está sendo esse pois o inicializador de `Person` não está passando pela `property`, ao invés disso estou atribuido o valor diretamente à variável `self.__name = name`, porém, se eu alterar para `self.name = name` recebo o erro dizendo que 'super' não tem um atributo 'name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MatheusSaraiva, vejo dois problemas no seu código, e estão relacionados com o conceito dos `getters` e `setters`.

Primeiro ponto, é que você está chamando no seu `init` a variável oculta para fazer a atribuição, e portanto, o `setter` não vai ser chamado, e assim, o `overwrite` nunca vai ter a chance de ser atribuído, a não ser que no seu código você faça alguma atribuição do tipo `ms.name = "x"`, quando efetivamente o `setter` vai rodar. 
 
Para resolver isso, é só trocar no `init` da classe `Person` o `self.__name = name` por `self.name = name`.
 
O segundo problema é mais profundo, e eu mesmo fiz vários testes para conseguir resolver. Inclusive encontrei um [bug antigo](https://bugs.python.org/issue14965) do Python relacionado à hierarquia dos `setters` e `getters`.

Essas questões estão com o seu código `super().name = 'override'`:
- A primeira coisa, e mais séria, é que quando você chama `super()`, sem explicitar os argumentos, seu programa vai puxar os valores `self.__class__, self` como argumentos, ou seja, a classe atual, no caso `Myself` e o objeto instanciado, no caso `ms`. Mas como estamos falando de uma propriedade da classe, ao deixar o `self` como segundo argumento, ele não vai reconhecer a propriedade de classe como parte desse objeto, e por isso o erro que você viu. Por esse motivo, precisamos explicitar os argumentos do super 
- A segunda é que você fez uma atribuição direta ao invés de usar o método `fset()`, que é aquele que define, por trás dos panos, o que o `decorator @property` está fazendo ao definir os métodos dos `setters` e `getters`, então isso precisa estar explicito. 
Usando essas correções no seu código, ele corrigido fica assim:

```
@Person.name.setter
def name(self, value):
    super(self.__class__, self.__class__).name.fset(self, 'override')
```

Comment: Grato! Algumas finções são novas para mim como é o caso da função `fset`, Também não sabia que `super()` recebia parâmetros, vou ler a documentação sobre elas.

Answer (score 0):

[[TL;DR]](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/inheritance-property)

Veja essa estrategia:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = None
    @property    
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
    @foo.setter    
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

class Bar(Foo):
    @Foo.foo.getter
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo * -1 if type(self._foo)==int else self._foo

bar = Bar()
bar2 = Bar()

# Alterando a propriedade foo da instancia bar atraves da classe Foo
bar.foo = "foo is Foo's property"
print('valor de foo na instancia bar:',bar.foo)
valor de foo na instancia bar: foo is Foo's property

# Alterando a propriedade foo da instancia bar atraves da propria instancia
bar.foo = 99
print('Valor de foo alterado pela instancia: ',bar.foo)
Valor de foo alterado pela instancia:  -99

print('Valor de foo na instancia bar2: ',bar2.foo)
Valor de foo na instancia bar2:  None
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/inheritance-property).